# Get gateway ip address in android

Tags: android, ip, gateway

How to get gateway IP details , There is option using wifimanager but. If there is no wify how to find gateway,dns and other details in android device when connected using usb tethering.

Comment: you can try the solution provided in the link, provided by Muhammad Zeeshan. or you can implement a http trace using the following method...[HTTP Trace](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpTrace.html#HttpTrace%28java.net.URI%29)

Comment: You can also use [RoutetoHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestRouteToHost%28int,%20int%29) this gives the path to the host, the first IP address would be the Gateway (if no Proxy is used).

Comment: Do research the [Connectivity Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

Comment: Actually Gateway, DNS and other details will be available but  hidden from mobile user by the mobile operator. You can see the APN settings for more details.

Answer (score 24):

I'm using cyanogenmod 7.2 on android 2.3.4, then just open terminal emulator and type:

```
$ ip addr show
$ ip route show
```

Comment: For Android 4.4 kitkat i also used Terminal emulator app and type the
commands provided here. it works.

Comment: Lollipop 5.0.1.  Works for me as well.

Answer (score 17):

On Android 7 works it:

```
 ip route get 8.8.8.8
```

output will be:
8.8.8.8 via gateway...

Comment: Thanks! On most linux systems either `netstat -rn` or `ip route show` will work, but on Android only `ip route get` shows the gateway.

Comment: On my case, `ip route show` just output broadcast address, while `ip route get` works

Answer (score 16):

I wanted to post this answer as an update for users of more recent Android builds (CM11/KitKat/4.4.4). I have not tested any of this with TouchWiz or older Android releases so YMMV.

The following commands can be run in all the usual places (ADB, Terminal Emulator, shell scripts, Tasker).

List all available properties:

```
getprop
```

Get WiFi interface:

```
getprop wifi.interface
```

WiFi properties:

```
getprop dhcp.wlan0.dns1
getprop dhcp.wlan0.dns2
getprop dhcp.wlan0.dns3
getprop dhcp.wlan0.dns4
getprop dhcp.wlan0.domain
getprop dhcp.wlan0.gateway
getprop dhcp.wlan0.ipaddress
getprop dhcp.wlan0.mask
```

The above commands will output information regardless of whether WiFi is actually connected at the time.

Use either of the following to check whether *wlan0* is on or not:

```
ifconfig wlan0

netcfg | awk '{if ($2=="UP" && $3 != "0.0.0.0/0") isup=1} END {if (! isup) exit 1}'
```

Use either of the following to get the IP address of wlan0 (only if it is connected):

```
ifconfig wlan0 | awk '{print $3}'

netcfg | awk '/^wlan0/ {sub("(0\\.0\\.0\\.0)?/[0-9]*$", "", $3); print $3}'
```

Just for thoroughness, to get your public Internet-facing IP address, you're going to want to use an external service. To obtain your public IP:

```
wget -qO- 'http://ipecho.net/plain'
```

To obtain your public hostname:

```
wget -qO- 'http://ifconfig.me/host'
```

Or to obtain your public hostname directly from your IP address:

```
(nslookup "$(wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain)" | awk '/^Address 1: / { if ($NF != "0.0.0.0") {print $NF; exit}}; /name =/ {sub("\\.$", "", $NF); print $NF; exit}') 2>/dev/null
```

Note: The aforementioned `awk` command seems overly complicated only because is able to handle output from various versions of `nslookup`. Android includes a minimal version of `nslookup` as part of `busybox` but there is a standalone version as well (often included in `dnsutils`).

Comment: Android 7.0 do not have `getprop dhcp`

Answer (score 4):

Go to terminal

```
$ adb -s UDID shell
$ ip addr | grep inet 
or
$ netcfg | grep inet
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you expand it by adding some text to explain how it works / how it solves the problem?

Comment: @gung it doesn't. That's just the self-assigned ip address, not the gateway address...

Answer (score 2):

DNS server is obtained via

```
getprop net.dns1
```

UPDATE: as of Android Nougat 7.x, ifconfig is present, and netcfg is gone. So ifconfig can be used to find the IP and netmask.

Comment: What does that have to do with the gateway address?

Comment: "If there is no [Wifi] how to find gateway, dns and other details" from the OP.. None of the other answers provided that detail.

Comment: how come this lists DNS servers I don't want my device using (IPv6) and it seems to prefer to use these instead of the dhcp.wlan0.dns* entries it should be using?

Comment: @rakslice it doesn't. Some home router's dns and gateway have the same ip address as the router's address.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ...;
LinkProperties linkProperties = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.GetActiveNetwork());
for (RouteInfo routeInfo: linkProperties.getRoutes()) {
    if (routeInfo.IsDefaultRoute() && routeInfo.hasGateway()) {
        return routeInfo.getGateway();
    }
}
```

Comment: Call requires API level 29

Comment: The `RouteInfo.hasGateway` call is API level 29, but its possible that `RouteInfo.getGateway` is still useful at API level 21. Also of note, `ConnectivityManager.GetActiveNetwork` is deprecated as of API level 29.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well for me. Tested on Touchwiz 5.1, LineageOS 7.1, and CyanogenMod 11.

```
ip route list match 0 table all scope global
```

Gives output similar to this:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  table wlan0  proto static
```

Answer (score 0):

Install terminal emulator app, then to see routing table run `iproute` from the command prompt. Does not require root permissions. I don't know how to get the DNS server. There's no `/etc/resolv.conf` file. You can try `nslookup www.google.com` and see what it reports for your server, but on my phone it reports `0.0.0.0` which isn't too helpful.

Answer (score -1):

This solution will give you the Network parameters. Check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387036/how-to-get-gateway-and-subnet-mask-details-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: Solution you are referring uses wifimanager which does not work when device is not connected to wify. how to find these details when device is connected by usb tethering or through gprs.