# Find ip address of wifi hotspot in android

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I want to connect multiple android phones to PC via Wi-Fi. To implement this, I've created a hotspot on my PC using Connectify and have connected all phones to it.Now, in order to communicate with PC, i need its IP address.

I've researched a lot and found ways to find IP address of phone but not Wi-fi hotspot. Please help me out.

Comment: You need the gateway address http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387036/how-to-get-gateway-and-subnet-mask-details-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Probably you use a server app on PC side. In this case:

1. Create a any UDP port and keep it opened all time.
2. Use UDP port discovery process to find the target PC in a network.

Use this method you can always find a target PC also in a standalone WiFi networks. Also I suggest to use a usefull [Kryonet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) library which provides a *[discoverHost](http://kryonet.googlecode.com/svn/api/com/esotericsoftware/kryonet/Client.html#discoverHosts%28int,%20int%29)* method.

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients = wifiApManager.getClientList(false);

    for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) 
    {
    wifi_ip = "IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() ;

    }
```

This will get you the IP Address of the wifi hotspot