# Manipulating netmasks, subnets, etc. in Java?

Tags: java, ip, guava

I was wondering if there are any good Java libraries for manipulating netmasks, subnets, etc. As far as I can tell, Java's [net](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) package and Guava's [net](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/net/package-summary.html) package don't include these capabilities.

In Python, I've been using [netaddr](http://pythonhosted.org//netaddr/) and I've been wondering if there's anything similarly powerful in Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to get subnet mask using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221517/how-to-get-subnet-mask-using-java)

Comment: See also `SubnetUtils.java` from [org.apache.commons.net.util](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/jacoco/org.apache.commons.net.util/index.html)

Comment: Google "java netmasks subnets" for more interesting links